# How to apply or Map a function to a 2 variables nested list

Tags: pure-function

I tried to understand the mechanism of pure function tricks. Imaging I have a nested list generated by:

```
list=Table[{p, q}, {p, 1, 9, 2}, {q, -p, p, 2}]
```

Result:

```
>    {{{1, -1}, {1, 1}}, {{3, -3}, {3, -1}, {3, 1}, {3,     3}}, {{5,
> -5}, {5, -3}, {5, -1}, {5, 1}, {5, 3}, {5,     5}}, {{7, -7}, {7, -5}, {7, -3}, {7, -1}, {7, 1}, {7, 3}, {7,     5}, {7, 7}}, {{9, -9}, {9,
> -7}, {9, -5}, {9, -3}, {9, -1}, {9,     1}, {9, 3}, {9, 5}, {9, 7}, {9, 9}}}
```

And a function:

```
Fun[x_, y_] := Total[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]
```

I want the Fun to apply to each pair of the `list` to calculate the sum of all the result.

Should I use something like `Fun[#1,#2]&/@list` ? But it never works out, idk why.Thanks for your help!

Comment: Take a look at Mike's and Chris's answers, and notice the difference between `Apply` and `Map`, both are great tools, both can be made to work in the same situations, but usually one is more suited to the task at hand.  Compare the results of `f @@ {1, 2}`, `f @@@ {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}`, and `f /@ {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}`

Answer (score 3):

Apply `Fun` at level 2 of `list`.

```
list = Table[{p, q}, {p, 1, 9, 2}, {q, -p, p, 2}];

Fun[x_, y_] := Total[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]

Apply[Fun, list, {2}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just re-define your function to

```
Fun2[{x_, y_}] := Total[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]
```

then

```
Map[Fun2, list, {2}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem as follows:

```
llist = Flatten[list, 1]
Apply[Fun, llist, 1]
```

If the structure of list should be kept

```
Table[Apply[Fun, list[[i]], -1], {i, 1, Length[list]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to keep the structure of the list you can do something like

```
In[1]:= list = Table[{p, q}, {p, 1, 9, 2}, {q, -p, p, 2}];

In[2]:= Fun[x_, y_] := Total[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]

In[3]:= Map[Fun @@ # &, list, {2}]

Out[3]= {{5/2, 5/2}, {3 + Sqrt[2], 21/2, 21/2, 
  3 + Sqrt[2]}, {5 + Sqrt[2], 69/2, 53/2, 53/2, 69/2, 
  5 + Sqrt[2]}, {7 + Sqrt[2], 149/2, 117/2, 5 + Sqrt[2], 5 + Sqrt[2], 
  117/2, 149/2, 7 + Sqrt[2]}, {9 + Sqrt[2], 261/2, 213/2, 
  3 + Sqrt[10], 165/2, 165/2, 3 + Sqrt[10], 213/2, 261/2, 
  9 + Sqrt[2]}}
```